# Is it safe to send credit card IDs to clients?

Tags: paypal

PayPal will give you an ID for each credit card you create e.g. `CARD-5BT058015C739554AKE2GCEI`:

```java
CreditCard creditCard = CreditCard.get(apiContext,
                    "CARD-5BT058015C739554AKE2GCEI");
```

Is it safe to send this ID to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe as PayPal tokenization service complies with EMV standard for securing transactions.

The *vault-and-pay* card-ID (token) can be only used thru PayPal OAuth authentication on **your REST APP** to

1. Exchange for card details with PayPal REST Vault service.
2. Be set as a payment funding source (`credit_card_token` object) on `payment` API, within the same REST application where it gets vaulted

While the tokenized ID is unreadable/meaningless for a customer, you may optionally display the user-friendly infor : card type mark (VISA, MC, AMEX, etc) and the last 4-digit card number in your customer's profile